# jquery array of objects append value if object is present

Tags: jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have an array of objects in javascript. What I want is to check one property of the objects in the array and if that property is present then another property should be appended, else create new array of objects. The array of objects is like this:

```
[{
    filtercolumnname: "countrycode",
    filterValue: "US,UK"
}]
```

I have to check if `filtercolumnname` is present in that array then add another value to existing values like `US,UK,IE,IN` else create new array. So the array should be:

```
[{
    filtercolumnname: "countrycode",
    filterValue: "US,UK,IE,IN"
}]
```

I tried this but not able to think how to active this

```
Var SelectedAttribute = "countrycode";
SelectedPoints = JSON.parse(ChartProperties[this._id]);
if (!SelectedPoints.hasOwnProperty("filterArray")) {
    (SelectedPoints.filterArray).each(function() {
        if (SelectedPoints.filterArray.filterColumnName.match(SelectedAttribute)) {
            SelectedPoints.filterArray.filterValue += series.points[sender.data.region.Region.PointIndex].x;
        } else {
            jsondata.filterArray.push({ 
                "filterValue": series.points[sender.data.region.Region.PointIndex].x, 
                "filterColumnName": SelectedAttribute 
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my issue.

```
 SelectedPoints = JSON.parse(ChartProperties[this._id]);

    Var SelectedAttribute = "countrycode";
    if (SelectedPoints.hasOwnProperty("filterArray"))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < SelectedPoints.filterArray.length; i++) {
            if (SelectedPoints.filterArray[i].filterColumnName.match(SelectedAttribute)) {
                SelectedPoints.filterArray[i].filterValue += "," + series.points[sender.data.region.Region.PointIndex].x;
            } else {
                jsondata.filterArray.push({ "filterValue": series.points[sender.data.region.Region.PointIndex].x, "filterColumnName": SelectedAttribute });
            }
        }
    } else {
        SelectedPoints["filterArray"] = [];
        SelectedPoints.filterArray.push({ "filterValue": series.points[sender.data.region.Region.PointIndex].x, "filterColumnName": SelectedAttribute });
        ChartProperties[this._id]= JSON.stringify(SelectedPoints);
    }
```